# pdfMake / html2canvas is way too big for PDF output, how to resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas, pdfmake

I'm trying to convert a section of my HTML page into a PDF file. I don't want the whole page because it contains buttons, etc. that aren't necessary.

So I created a div that has a height 0 and adding the content I need to print into the underlying div then removed elements and printed. All my code is below. It works well but the pdf is WAY too zoomed in and I can't fix it.  I've attached my code and resulting pdf output below. I've tried so many different settings. Does anyone have tips?

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; height: 0;">
  <div id="mainClone"></div>
</div>


function printPDF()
{


html2canvas($('#mainClone'), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var data = canvas.toDataURL();
            var docDefinition = {
                pageSize: {
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 'auto'
                },
                content: [{
                    image: data,
                    //width: width,
                    //height: height,
                }],
                pageSize: 'letter',
                pageOrientation: 'landscape',
                pageMargins: [ 5, 5, 5, 5 ],
            };
            pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
        }
    });

}

$('#PrintPDF').click(function () {
    $('#mainClone').html($('#main').html());
    $('#mainClone').find(".calendar-prev").hide();
    //remove more html elemnent we don't need

    printPDF();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can make it while still using jspdf, instead of creating an extra div, go with your default page and with any unnecessary element(which you do not want into your PDF) add this

```
data-html2canvas-ignore="true"
```

to each unnecessary element.

this will ignore that element and will not put into your generated PDF.